# Python urlopener not retrieving tables and lists

Tags: python, urllib

I am trying to make a simple webscraper where I take the information off a HTML page. It's simple but I have a problem I can't seem to solve:
When I download the HTML page by myself and parse it using BeautifulSoup, it parses everything and gives me all the data, this is ok but I don't need to do this. Instead I am trying to using a link instead which doesn't seem to be working. Whenever I use the link using the "urlopen" function and parse the page using BeautifulSoup, it always seems to completely ignore/exclude some lists and tables from the HTML file. These tables appear when I look up the page online using the "Inspect Element" method, and they also appear when I download the HTML page myself but they never appear when I use the "urlopen" function. I even tried encoding post data and sending it as an argument of the function but it doesn't seem to work that way either.

```
import bs4
from urllib.request import urlopen as uReq
from urllib.parse import urlencode as uEnc
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup

my_url = 'https://sp.com.sa/en/tracktrace/?tid=RB961555017SG'

#data = {'tid':'RB961555017SG'}
#sdata = uEnc(data)
#sdata = bytearray(sdata, 'utf-8')

uClient = uReq(my_url, timeout=2)  # opening url or downloading the webpage
page_html = uClient.read() # saving html file in page_html
uClient.close() # closing url or connection idk properly

page_soup = soup(page_html, "html.parser") # parsing the html file and saving

updates = page_soup.findAll("div",{"class":"col-sm-12"})
#updates = page_soup.findAll("ol", {})

print(updates)
```

These tables contain the information I need, is there anyway I can fix this?

Answer (score 0):

request works a bit differently than a browser. E.g. it does not actually run JavaScript.

In this case the table with info is generated by a script rather than hardcoded in HTML. You can see the actual source-code using "view-source:" followed by the url.
view-source:https://sp.com.sa/en/tracktrace/?tid=RB961555017SG

So, we'd want to run that script some way. The easiest is to use "selenium", which uses the driver of your browser. Then simply take the loaded html and run that through BS4. I noticed that there is a more specific tag you can use rather than "col-sm-12". Hope it helps :)

```
import bs4
from urllib.request import urlopen as uReq
from urllib.parse import urlencode as uEnc
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup

my_url = 'https://sp.com.sa/en/tracktrace/?tid=RB961555017SG'

from selenium import webdriver
import time

chrome_path = "path of chrome driver that fits your current browser version"
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_path)
driver.get(my_url)
time.sleep(5)                 #to make sure it's loaded
page_html = driver.page_source
driver.quit()

page_soup = soup(page_html, "html.parser") # parsing the html file and saving
updates = page_soup.findAll("table",{"class":"table-shipment table-striped"}) #The table is more specific to you wanted data than the col-sm-12 so I'd rather use that.
print(updates)
```

Comment: Thank you for replying!
I've tried to run the code but unfortunately, it gives me an error saying ```Permission Error:  [Winerror 5] Access is denied ``` and also ```Message: 'chromedriver_win32' executable may have wrong permissions.```
I downloaded the correct version of the chrome driver for my browser and this doesn't seem to be an issue of that.

Comment: Try chrome_path=r'C:/path/to/chromedriver.exe'   (note the 'r' before path). Often directory-stuff gets a bit strict in python :)